# Getting the RAM/CPU usage of a specific process in Java

Tags: java, process, tasklist

I am trying to gather data of a process' RAM and CPU usage in Windows. More specifically, I need to distinguish two processes apart (that can have the same name) or get the process's information directly.

For example, I may need to gather data from process X, that may have the same name as process Y. I am using `tasklist.exe` for this:

```
String line;
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tasklist.exe");
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.startsWith("java.exe")) // I only want the processes that have 'java.exe' for a name.
        System.out.println(line);
}
```

Running this gives me two different processes, with the same name:

```
java.exe                     28912 Console                    9     18,664 K
java.exe                     36388 Console                    9     19,896 K
```

In this case, I only want to gather information from the second process. I would think that I could use the PID as an identifier, **but it seems that each run of this program changes the PID of the processes shown above**.

The question: How can I gather data from the same process multiple times, even though it has a counterpart with the same name? (How can I know which one is which when I run `tasklist` again?)

Answer (score 1):

I would use `jps` to get the details of each Java process.

e.g.

```
$ jps -lvm
22490 sun.tools.jps.Jps -lvm -Dapplication.home=/mnt/opt/jdk1.8.0_66 -Xms8m
6495 spigot-1.9.jar
```

One Java process is `jps` as it can see itself and the other is running spigot.

This information can be used with `tasklist` or `ps` to get more information about those processes by the id.

If the command lines are the same I suggest adding a dummy property to make it easier to tell them apart e.g.

```
java -Dprocess=MyFirstProcess ... your normal command line args ...
```

You can add arbitrary properties to the command line provided they are ignored (and not too long), they are harmless.